# Get partial DataFrames using multiple indexes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to get a part of it passing a list of names as index 1 and index2:

This is an example of my dataframe:

```
| index1  |  index2  |        |
|-----------------------------|
| chicago |  rome    |  0.22  |
| berlin  |  praha   |  1.22. |
...
```

I want to get a new dataframe which will contain only does tuples which index1 and index2 are in a list of cities.

If i do:

```py
df.loc['chicago', 'rome']
```

i get `0.22` but I want to pass a list of cities in both index1 and 2: something like this:

```
df.loc[list_ofCities1, list_ofCities2]
```

Is there any way to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, need `tuples` for one pair:

```
df.loc[('chicago', 'rome')]
```

For check multiple values use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html):

```
m1 = df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(list_ofCities1) 
m2 = df.index.get_level_values(1).isin(list_ofCities2)

df = df[m1 & m2]
```

Or [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with list of tuples with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.isin(list(zip(list_ofCities1, list_ofCities2)))]
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdec'),
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabgg')
}).set_index(['A','F'])['E']


list_ofCities1 = list('abc')
list_ofCities2 = list('ang')

df = df[df.index.isin(list(zip(list_ofCities1, list_ofCities2)))]
print (df)
A  F
a  a    5
c  g    4
Name: E, dtype: int64
```

Another idea is use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) with `loc`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.intersection(list(zip(list_ofCities1, list_ofCities2)))]
print (df)
A  F
a  a    5
c  g    4
Name: E, dtype: int64
```